# javascript which happens first j.sort().filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

Combining method calls `j.sort().filter()` which happens first, sort() or filter().
I'd rather `.filter()` first so `.sort()` will have that much less work to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` is called, and the `filter` is called on whatever `sort` returns.

So if you want `filter` first, change the order: `j.filter().sort()`.

Note that that change has a hidden effect: `r = j.sort().filter();` *sorts* the array `j` refers to, in-place, and then creates a new array with the filtered elements which ends up referenced by `r`. So `j` is sorted (as is `r`). But `r = j.filter().sort();` *first* creates the new array from the filtered elements, and then sorts that new array. So `r` is sorted, but `j` is not.

Comment: Thanks.  Always nice to see you're answering.

Comment: Explain this please.  Why would people bother voting this question down?

Comment: @user5903880: I could only guess lack of research. But it's a guess.